# Accessing Dynamically created HTML table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have a page that is using Javascript to output data to a HMTL table that is working fine using the method below in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("statsoutput").appendChild(table1);
```

However I am now adding a button to download the table into an excel file if the user so wishes. However I can't get started with this as when I try to access the generated table it seems to be empty even though I can see the table has been populated.

For example the length of the table seems to be zero when I call it on the button press

```
 var tablesize = document.getElementById("statsoutput").rows.length;
```

This gives me zero as a result.

If I try

```
var table = document.getElementById("statsoutput");
```

This returns     [object HTMLTableElement]

But I am stuck as I can't seem to access anything from the HTML table I have generated when I press my button to being the process of writing it to an excel file.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Apologies HTML code is

```
<button onclick="saveFile()">Excel</button>

<div class="tab" id = "Tabs" style="display:none">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTable(event, 'Stats')" id = "defaultOpen">Stats</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTable(event, 'Hands')">Hands</button>
</div>
<div id="Stats" class="tabcontent" >
    <table id="statsoutput">
    </table>
</div>

<div id="Hands" class="tabcontent" >
    <div id="output">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the html code please

Comment: Sure sorry  <button onclick="saveFile()">Excel</button>

<div class="tab" id = "Tabs" style="display:none">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTable(event, 'Stats')" id = "defaultOpen">Stats</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTable(event, 'Hands')">Hands</button>
</div>
<div id="Stats" class="tabcontent" >
    <table id="statsoutput">
    </table>
</div>

<div id="Hands" class="tabcontent" >
    <div id="output">
    </div>
</div>

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows.length` try this

Comment: Please don't post blocks of code in comments. Just edit your question.

Comment: Thanks Yogen but I'm afraid the gerElementsByTagName didn't work :(

Comment: `statsoutput` is your table and `document.getElementById("statsoutput").appendChild(table1);` you are adding another table inside table.

Comment: Thanks again. So I need to change how I'm assigning my dynamically created table in the first place?

Comment: `document.getElementById('statsoutput').querySelector('table')` This will first table inside specified id.

Comment: Thanks again, this just gives me null I'm afraid.

Comment: Using    var table = document.getElementById("statsoutput").innerHTML; will give me the HTML for the table, however it just seems to be the text for the HTML so I need to do a bit more work to use this to about to excel. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: getElementById returns a reference to an Element. Which is an interface that all HTML node types adhere to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element . Rows is not a property of Element. Each HTML tag has an implementation that has the methods of Element implemented, such as HTMLDivElement. There are libraries for converting HTML Tables to Excel. For example https://codepen.io/kostas-krevatas/pen/mJyBwp

Comment: Thanks again, yes I started with the example below but I would like to write to multiple sheets in the workbook which I don't think is possible using that method! Thanks for all the help!